# Регистрация COM объекта

Tags: windows, vista, com, c, c++

Как зарегистрировать COM объект в Windows Vista? Есть ли какие-нибудь отличия от этого процесса в других версиях Windows, например, от Windows XP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть у вас есть COM объект someComObj.dll. Для регистрации этого компонента нужно выполнить команду в терминале:

```
C:\>regsvr32.exe /path/to/component/someComObj.dll
```

Эта процедура одинакова на всех версиях Windows.

Comment: После выполнения этой команды не было ни одного сообщения: ни об ошибке, ни об успехе, при этом объект не вызвать. Windows Vista x64.

Comment: После выполнения команды должно выводиться сообщение, которое даст понять, зарегистрирован компонент или нет. Скорее всего вам не хватило прав администратора. Они нужны для записи в реестр. Попробуйте запустить терминал от имени администратора.

Comment: Как понять путь /path/to/component/someComObj.dll, почему слеши в другую сторону? Я когда пишу вот так C:\>regsvr32.exe C:\Users\my\source\repos\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2\bin\Release\ClassLibrary2.dll мне пишет отказано в доступе, почему?

Comment: @Winteriscoming Пожалуйста, задайте ваш вопрос вопросов, а не комментарием. Для этого нажмите на кнопку «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» справа в верхней части сайта.

Comment: Так ваш же вопрос, вам сложно уточнить?

Comment: @Winteriscoming  У вас совершенно другой вопрос. Модель Stack Overflow — одна проблема — один вопрос. Пожалуйста, задайте ваш вопрос отдельно, при необходимости сославшись на этот. Таким образом наша общая база знаний будет иметь правильную структуру.

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле, в 64 битной Windows имеется две утилиты `regsvr32`.   Одна находится в **с:\windows\system32**, и предназначена для регистрации 64-битных библиотек.   Вторая находится в **с:\windows\SysWOW64** и предназначена для регистрации 32-битных библиотек.   Главный косяк в том, что по умолчанию вызывается 64-битная утилита, но с помощью нее зарегистрировать 32-битную библиотеку скорее всего не удастся. [Пруф](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282747)
То есть, чтобы зарегистрировать в Windows 7, например, 32-битную библиотеку (а библиотека, написанная на с++ с огромной долей вероятности 32-битная) нужно сделать следующий финт:
    c:>c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32 <full_lib_name>.dll
либо так
    c:>cd \windows\syswow64
    c:\windows\syswow64>regsvr32 <full_lib_name>.dll

Comment: > библиотека, написанная на с++ с огромной долей вероятности 32-битная

forman.jpg